# When I am not calling the function then also it is printing

Tags: python, function

```
def mult_x_add_y(number, x, y):
    print(number*x + y)
result = mult_x_add_y(1, 3, 1)
```

In this python code I am not calling the function than also its printing the value 4. Why is it so?

Comment: Because you have a `print()` inside the function

Comment: Your question makes little sense. Functions don't execute if not called. Your code *does* call the function. Are you asking why a function which has a `print` statement prints something? Why wouldn't it?

Comment: If you don not want the result to be printed, then use `return number*x + y` instead of `print(number*x + y)`

Comment: function without a return statement will return `None`. Possibly you are expecting that the value of the result will be some `integer` but it will be `None` ( Because you are just printing it but not returning ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You are calling the function by the code

result = **mult_x_add_y(1, 3, 1)**

So now the function will be called or executed. You have provided **print()** function inside your function defenition. That why the answer is printed.

To print the answer only when you needed you have to return the computetd value rather than printing on there.

> The modified code is:

```
def mult_x_add_y(number, x, y):
    return number*x + y
result = mult_x_add_y(1, 3, 1)

print(result)
```

> Result:

```
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are printing the result in the function definition. You most likely want to `return` it instead.

```py
def mult_x_add_y(number, x, y):
    return number * x + y


result = mult_x_add_y(1, 3, 1)
```

If you try to print `result` in your current code, it will print `None`.